# C# MDI Form to Pass Object By Reference

Tags: c#, object, global, pass-by-reference, mdi

Hi I have Created a c# MDI Application to connect to Hardware using the Serial Port (Or USB).I want Each Child_Form to write and Receive Protocol Information from the Serial_port Object created on the MDI_Form Instance.

Is there a Way how I can have my serialPort instance global to my project? I only want One Connection but all child forms must have access to the Connection.

Answer (score 0):

declare the serialPort instance as public static, then you can access it any where in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You should add another constructor in all child forms, when in MDI_Form calling them use overload constructor.

In all child forms add second constructor

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    private Port _port = new Port();

    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ChildForm(Port port) : this()
    {
        _port = port;
    }

    ...
}
```

In MDI_Form when call use this overload

```
public partial class MDI_Form : Form
{
    private Port _port = new Port();

    ...

    private void ChildToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm cf = new ChildForm(_port);
        cf.MdiParent = this;
        cf.Show();
    }

    ...
}
```